# String Format not working

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, string.format

I am trying to display a number, stored in a dataset as a string, as a phone number. I have a label that Binds to a value but doesn't display the format that I passed as an arg:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl005108002" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "phone number", "{0:(###) ###-####}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

As a test I tried to pass the formated string into the dataitem but that didn't work either. Is there something else I need to do in order to use this function?

```
m_Row("phone number") = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", value)
```

The value displays in both cases as: 04152543926

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to do the databinding in my codebehind:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl005108002" runat="server" Text="" OnDataBinding="lbl005108002_DataBinding"></asp:Label>
```

In codebehind:

```
protected void lbl005108002_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    lbl.Text = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", (int)(Eval("phone number")));
}
```

I think the key is that cast to `int` so that the formatter knows how to deal with the value you are sending it.  I prefer doing this in codebehind because sometimes trying to cram everything inline makes things less explicit.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I had to convert it to an int first and that is what I was not doing

Answer (score 0):

What type is value?  This seems to format ok for me:

```
     int phone_num = 1231231234;
     string f = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", phone_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is:

Dim i as Integer = 5551234567
Dim s As String =  i.ToString("(###) ###-####")

The ToString is the fast way I use. What I did is in th eCommand window I did this:

```
? 5551234567.ToString("(###) ###-####")
```

The result was:

```
"(555) 123-4567"
```

So I am sure it works. Good luck!